# Segmentation fault when printf %s is called

Tags: c, printf, segmentation-fault, fault

There is a tiny part of my code in C.

```
read(fd,&bufferSize,sizeof(bufferSize);
buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
read(fd,&buffer,bufferSize);
printf("%d",buffer);
fflush(stdout);
printf("%s",buffer);
fflush(stdout);
```

When I print buffer with `%d` format, it's working, but when I try to consider the buffer as a string, I get segmentation fault. SIGSEGV occurs even when I use `strcmp` or other functions like that.

Comment: Also: `read()` returns a value. **Use it!**

Comment: `buffer` may lack _null character_ termination.  To not access outside  its allocation nor data read, `int n = read(fd,&buffer,bufferSize); printf("%.*s",n, buffer);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
read(fd,&buffer,bufferSize);
```

Here, `buffer` is the address of the start of your buffer. So, when you call the above function, you as passing in **the address of your address**.

Thus, you can see why it segfaults, because the address passed in is not the actual address of the buffer. Replace that line with

```
read(fd,buffer,bufferSize);
```

Comment: And that mistake is caught by a compilation with all warnings enabled, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) - you would get at least a warning, and probably more